# How to send my PDF file to a python script instead of a physical printer?

Tags: python, printing, redmon

Hello i´m currently using RedMon to try to redirect a PDF file that I´m gonna print. I want to send this PDF to a Python script instead of printing it. I was using RedMon to achieve the activation of the Python script (.exe) but I don´t know how to get access and manipulate the PDF file.

Comment: Getting access to a PDF file from a Python script should be simple. You can write the Python script to open this PDF file from a known location or pass the location as an argument. Being able to manipulate is a different story. Depending on your use case, you'll need to use a Python module that can operate on PDF files.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I´m aware of how to open files in python; the thing is that I need that the script get access to the PDF file by itself whenever I want to print the PDF file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.